# Auto-Encoder/Decoder - Generic Swapping Model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm just starting out in ML and I am interested in a model that can swap similar things in images, like doors or items on a desk. Is it possible to take a library like https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap which is meant to swap faces and train it to swap other things?

When I search for 'swapping' models, face-swapping is pretty much all I get, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology behind faceswaps using [two autoencoders](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml-blog/deepfakes) should also work for things instead of persons. The logic behind it stays the same, would just need enough training data.